# deleting chars in c++

Tags: c++, xcode, string, memory, random

I am making a program in C++ using Xcode that will generate random strings but when I do this it consumes an incredible amount of RAM. I have tried using .erase(); and .clear(); but neither seems to work.

here is my code:

```
void randStringMake(char *s, int l)
{
    // AlphaNumaric characters
    static const char AlphaNumaric[] = "abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyz" "ABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZ" "1234567890";

    for(int x = 0; x < l; x++) {
        s[x]=AlphaNumaric[rand() % (sizeof(AlphaNumaric) - 1)];
    }
    s[l] = 0;
}

char randString;

randStringMake(randString, 10);

std::cout << std::string(&randString) << "\n";
```

So i guess my question here, is how do i remove the string from the memory?

Comment: Without seeing your code, it's hard to give you advice.

Comment: We can't do much without the code ^^

Comment: Have you tried generating fewer strings or shorter strings?

Comment: erase() and clear() only remove content from the string, there is no guarantee that they deallocate the string memory. This is common for STL containers, since typical usage patterns show that deallocating a string buffer when removing content would be too much of a performance penalty. [This other SO question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/740030/how-to-release-the-unused-capacity-of-a-string) might give you some useful advice.

Comment: Forget seeing code, we don't even have a question here! What is your question?

Comment: I don't see any use of strings in the provided code snippet, only the writing of values into a character array.  How were you able to call .erase() or .clear() on a (char *)?

Comment: The code you've posted doesn't use std::string, so your question really makes no sense.

Comment: @RobK I have updated my code. Sorry for the confusion.

Comment: it seems you pass char variable as a pointer variable, does this code compile !!!

you need to make an array of 11 characters instead and pass it.

Comment: it does compile, i mean this is how my c++ teacher taught me how to do this. if its wrong, please correct me.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I made some minimal changes to your code so it compiles and runs. The main problem was `randString` was declared as a single `char` when it should be an array large enough to hold the generated string and a null terminator.

Note that the code as posted doesn't required `std::string` and shouldn't cause excessive memory use. If you still have a problem it's in code that you haven't shown.

```
#include <iostream>
#include <cstdlib>

void randStringMake(char *s, int l)
{
    // AlphaNumaric characters
    static const char AlphaNumaric[] = "abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyz" "ABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZ" "1234567890";

    for(int x = 0; x < l; x++) {
        s[x]=AlphaNumaric[rand() % (sizeof(AlphaNumaric) - 1)];
    }
    s[l] = 0;
}

int main()
{
    // randString should be an array to hold 10 chars + null terminator
    char randString[11];

    randStringMake(randString, 10);

    std::cout << randString << "\n";
}
```

Comment: thank you. that helps but do you know how to release any memory taken up by lots of strings?

Comment: I don't see you adding anything to the free store? Are you trying to remove memory off the stack?

Comment: Also, you spelled `AlphaNumeric` incorrectly (in the original post above). It's minor, but should this code ever be maintained by someone else, they may have a hard time finding variables that are not properly spelled.

Comment: I'm really sorry if I'm not making sense. Could someone explain to me why my program is taking up large amounts of memory (like 2 GB), if I'm not even allocating any manually to the strings? If i sound like an idiot, its because I'm definitely a newbie!

Comment: @WillBrickner: This small bit of code _can't_ be the source of your memory consumption. Do you have a minimal example of code that reproduces the problem? Does your program appear to run correctly (aside from using 2GB) or does it crash? Does your program use `malloc`, `new`, or recursion?

Comment: it runs perfectly, it will crash xcode after a while though. what im actually doing is everything inside the main() function is in a while loop which looks like this:

    bool booleanState;
    while (!booleanState) {
        char* RandPass = NULL; // init the var
        
        randStringMake(RandPass, length_i); // make the random string with the length of whatever length_i equals
        std::cout << std::string(RandPass) << "\n"; // print the string version of randpass
    }

Comment: @WillBrickner: This part is a problem `char* RandPass = NULL;` because you then pass a NULL pointer to `randStringMake()` which causes it to write to an invalid address. How big is your program? It might help to edit your question and paste the __complete__ source code instead of these isolated snippets.

Comment: my program is only 75 or so lines of code. not anything too large, or anything that would cause the consumption of two gigs of memory. i was worried about posting my full source code here, because my end goal for this program is going to be a brute-force 'password recovery' tool, so i thought people would tell me to structure my whole project on a different idea, as I have seen that before many times on Stack Overflow, and that they would be unwilling to help me. so, should i just post all my code here? thanks in advance!

Comment: @WillBrickner: Ideally you should trim the code down to the bare minimum that reproduces the problem. If not, you could paste it into http://ideone.com/ and then post a link here.

Comment: char* RandPass =;
was supposed to be:
char* RandPass = NULL;

Comment: @WillBrickner: I tried not to change too much. Your function now builds a random string and returns it to the caller. That should get you past this problem. http://ideone.com/TZ8HU

Comment: Thank you so, so, SO much Blastfurnace! I spent literally all day looking for an answer to my problem.

Comment: @WillBrickner: I'm glad that helped. I suggest you stick with `std::string` unless you really, really need raw character arrays and pointers. The `std::string` type manages resources for you and has a lot of useful [built-in functions](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/string/basic_string).

Comment: wait, sorry haha, hold up. when i run it and use instruments to view how much ram is being consumed, and it turns out its over 1.5 gigs still after about 30 seconds. is there any way to remove the string from memory completely while still being able to access it later?

Comment: and by "still being able to access it later", i mean that i can still access the variable, not the actual content.

Comment: @WillBrickner: I'm not sure why it appears that way on your machine. I tested it with Visual C++ 2010 here and this code uses ~670K maximum. Does the memory in use keep rising while the program is running? Oh, and `RandPass.clear()` should clear the contents and leave the string empty.

Comment: yeah it does. maybe its my machine. ill try compiling it and running it in instruments as a command-line tool, and then see if it makes the ammount of memory its using top out at 512MB. thats what im shooting for, at this point.

Comment: @WillBrickner: Make sure your tool is showing actual memory in use and not something like virtual memory reserved.

Comment: yeah after about a min of running as a command line tool with the altered code, its topping off at about 300 MB of ram.